# SQL Server 2008 symmetric key opening with different passwords?

Tags: sql-server, passwords, encryption-symmetric

In my scenario I use a symmetric key to encrypt my asymmetric key, the latter is used to encrypt some sensitive data which should be available only to a selected ring of people.

The symmetric key is encrypted with password and what I need is the possibility to have several passwords for this key so that every password alone is enough to open this key.

I know that there is a possibility to add passwords to an existing symmetric key using

```
ALTER KEY MySymKey ADD ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'newpasswd'
```

The question is whether adding a new encryption by password already does it and every password here would do open it, or the key is just additionally encrypted by the new password and one has to provide all passwords and/or other encryption data (certificates, other keys etc.) to open this key?

If the latter is true, how can I create several duplicates of the same symmetric key but with different passwords?

Answer (score 1):

> I use a symmetric key to encrypt my asymmetric key

I really hope this is a typo and you're doing it the other way. The correct [hierarchy encryption](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189586.aspx) is always symmetric key to encrypt the data and certificate/asymmetric key to encrypt the encryption key.

As for your question: adding a new encryption to a key does not drop previous encryptions. Multiple passwords can be added to a key. Though, judging from your example, you are planning to add the password to the symmetric key, which is likely incorrect.

The reason why the hierarchy matters is driven by two factors:

- symmetric key encryption is fast, asymmetric key encryption is extremely slow. Therefore direct data encryption is always done by the fast key, the symmetric one.
- data encryption keys needs to be periodically changed to reduce the collision probability and mitigate some many analytical attacks, as well as to reduce the surface exposed in case of key loss. This is done by simply changing the key and encrypting *new* data with the new key (re-encrypting old data is not only prohibitive, but would also negate the very benefit of key rotation). The new key is encrypted with the user certificate/asymmetric key/password thus opening it for use.

Please spend some time and read the relevant MSDN articles (start with the one linked above), this stuff is *really easy* to mess up and you'll end up with either 'perfect encryption' (ie. you loose the ability to decrypt the data) or worse, a lot of smoke and mirrors that would obfuscate the fact that your key management and hierarchy is plain broken.

Comment: No, I am doing it that way too. I am aware of the classical encryption hierarchy and I actually needed a sort of right managements for asymmetric key, so that not everybody is allowed to use it. Since I can't use the MS SQL server for this policy I implemented the solution where I keep many versions of the same asymmetric key encrypted using different passwords -- the user has to provide a correct password to apply the asymmetric key. This is what I basically wanted.